# Using native Facebook App to post

Tags: c#, facebook, windows-phone-7, installed-applications

I'm new in WP7 developing but in my looking for a way to post something on Facebook I found only external framework based on Browser object for authentication or or ShareLink \ Shared Status tasks. Is it possible to use\post directly the Original Facebook App installed onto mobile phone to post on FB (as done by iPhone)?

Thanks.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

As you rightly mentioned, the only possible ways to share to facebook are from any external framework implemented in the app like [C# SDK](http://csharpsdk.org/) or  ShareLinkTask or ShareStatusTasks.

Unfortunately you cannot access the Facebook app in the Windows phone device.